# SQL select statement yielding same results as PL/pgSQL FOR loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am having a hard time understanding when to use a PL/pgSQL `FOR` loop vs. regular SQL.

This question is definitely showing my naïvite, but here is what I am confused about:

given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE bins  AS 
SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10) AS id;
```

if I wanted to add a plus 1 to the `id` field in every row, I would do this:

```
select id+1 from bins;
```

which would correctly return

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Now if I useed a PL/pgSQL function for this operation, it would look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_one(
n integer
) 
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT id
        FROM bins
    LOOP 
 RAISE NOTICE '%', rec.id+n;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

so then

```
select add_one(1)
```

would yield

```
-- Executing query:
select add_one(1)
NOTICE:  2
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  4
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  5
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  6
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  7
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  8
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  9
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  10
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
NOTICE:  11
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_one(integer) line 9 at RAISE
```

so my question is, the SQL select statement in a way acts like a for loop because in this example it adds a 1 to every row... which is the same thing that is happening in the PL/pgSQL function. is this an accurate description?

Comment: Your final comparison is kind of accurate. It's also kind of pointless. An axe can split wood, so can a bomb. What does that tell us? Nothing, really. The simple `SELECT` is many times faster, simpler, shorter and less error prone than looping in plpgsql. That's it.

Comment: Rather than noting that loops and SQL statements can be used to do some of the same things, it's more important to note that they can be used to do different things.  For example if you needed to construct and execute a series of SQL statements for which selection criteria (to be used in the WHERE clause) were stored in rows of a table, then looping over the rows of the table would be useful, whereas no single SQL statement would create and execute the whole series of SQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is accurate.

What is probably your biggest problem at this point is to understand the non-procedural nature of SQL. In this language you do not specify the steps required to reach a result, you only describe the result you want.

So the SQL statement you used above that you want `id`, increased by one, for every row in the table. If the database does this by running a loop internally or by an act of god is not your primary focus.

This is weird for many procedural programmers in the beginning, but it makes life better once you get used to it: you don't have to know all the database internals to figure out the best way to process a query. The *optimizer* does that for you, and usually better than you could do it yourself.

Of course it is healthy curiosity to want to know how a query is processed internally. For that you use the `EXPLAIN` statement. This is particularly necessary to analyze and fix performance problems.

The rule of thumb is that it is usually better to perform as much of the work as possible in one bigger SQL statement than in many simple small ones tied together with application code. This is because there is less overhead this way, but also because a bigger statement often opens more ways to the optimizer. For example, nested loops are the simplest, but not always the best way to solve a problem.

Comment: I have been using SQL for a few years now and the way you describe its use mindset "In this language you do not specify the steps required to reach a result, you only describe the result you want" is how I have been approaching SQL. The reason I ask this question is because I recently encountered a very complex task that I was not able to solve in SQL (subqueries, CTE'S, laterals were no use) and I had to figure it out using a pgsql for loop. It is still a bit unclear to me why my code required a for loop. but it worked.so as you say, its just healthy curiosity - thanks for the elucidation

Comment: The loop is required because PL/pgSQL is a *procedural language* (that's what the "PL" stands for). The way you process sets of results in procedural code is to loop through them. Of course the same thing happens in the database, it is just more efficient and you don't see it.

Comment: right of course...I meant to say that is that it was unclear to me exactly why I was not able to use pure SQL to yield the results I wanted.